# Custom Gallery View for Virtual Products

Tags: product-images, magento2.4.5

In Magento 2, how can I change the product gallery settings to show the nav as dots on mobile and thumbs on desktop? This needs to be for the Virtual Product Type ONLY.

I *think* I should be able to do this using view.xml, but I am not quite sure what that would look like.

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/jquery-widgets/gallery/